# Detected that 1 of your apps is targeting an old version of Android - Xamarin forms manifest file is targetSdkVersion33

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am confused why does google say "We've detected that your app is targeting an old version of Android"  I have checked my xamarin forms app and the manifest says

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="29" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
```

What am I missing?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can disregard or ignore the warning message for now because the action that Google will take if you don't upgrade your `targetSdkVersion` to **33** is only avoiding your apps from Google Play for users who have Android 13 & 14.

Additionally, I've noticed some users which have already updated their apps to `API 33`, and yet they still see the warning notification in the Google Play console. So, I think you can ignore it for now and wait until the 1st of Sept to see what will happen. Hopefully Google is aware of [this issue](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/230909154/google-play-target-api-policy-violation-notice?hl=en) and is trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If your targetSdkVersion in your android/build.gradle is 33, then you should be able to disregard this warning.

To make sure follow these steps:

> Select your app in the console and at the bottom of the main menu select "Policy Status" you should then see the warning. Click the blue
> arrow to see the detail and then click the link "View affected app
> bundles". There you will see which apps are causing the issue. You
> might find that it is a test track that has the issue (even if that
> test track is pause).

If the issue seems to be about an older version of the app (not the latest release), then you got the warning because of it and you will be able to release without need of further updates.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/230909154/google-play-target-api-policy-violation-notice?hl=en